# Как записать Select Колонка_1 From Таблица Where Колонка_2 = "А" в Android Studio?

Tags: android, mysql, база-данных, android-studio, sqlite

Есть листвью, в который подгружаются данные из курсора, в который на первом актвити передаются данные из первого столбца таблица, а на втором должны выводится все данные , где строчка в первом столбце = А, и так еще с 3мя активити, как мне записать формулу выше в курсор , и как взять Название элемента из lisview и передать его в следующую активти?

Answer (score 0):

Накидал примерный код. Отрефачишь сам, изменишь названия методов, вынесешь названия полей в константы.

Вот код хелпера

```
public class DBTestOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    DBTestOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "MY_DB", null, 1);
    }

    SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        if (database == null) {
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("MY_DB", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        return database;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + "MY_TABLE" + " ("
                + "id"          + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "column_1"    + " TEXT,"
                + "column_2"    + " TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
}
```

Вот класс с методами

```
public class DBTest {

    private DBTestOpenHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBTest(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DBTestOpenHelper(context);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        db.close();
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    private Cursor getCursor(String query) {
        return db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }

    private int getindex(Cursor c, String NAME) {
        return c.getColumnIndex(NAME);
    }

    public List<String> getColumn1List() {
        List<String> column1List = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor c = getCursor("SELECT column_1 FROM MY_TABLE");
        int column1 = getindex(c, "column_1");
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                column1List.add(c.getString(column1));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        return column1List;
    }

    public String getColumn1(int id) {
        String column1Result = "";
        Cursor c = getCursor("SELECT column_1 FROM MY_TABLE WHERE id = '" + id + "'");
        int column1 = getindex(c, "column_1");
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                column1Result = c.getString(column1);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        return column1Result;
    }

    public int addColumn1(String column1) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("column_1", column1);
        return (int) db.insert("MY_TABLE", null, cv);
    }

    public void editColumn1(int id, String column1) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("column_1", column1);
        db.update("MY_TABLE", cv, "id=" + id, null);
    }

    public boolean removeColumn1(int id) {
        try {
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE id = '" + id + "'");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {return false;}
    }
}
```

Вот так создаешь базу и работаешь с ней:

```
DBTest dbTest = new DBTest(getApplicationContext());
dbTest.addColumn1("A");
```

Comment: Нет, я может не так сформулировал вопрос, но у меня уже есть класс дбхелпер, мне именно в курсор надо занести формулу выше , т.е уже есть  c = db.rawQuery("select " + COLUMN_2 + " from " + TABLE + " where " + COLUMN_1= " А"  , null );

Вот этот код ,почему-то ,выдает ошибку. Так же вместо А должен стоять название элемента листвью

Comment: Какую ошибку?
Что пишет в логах?

Comment: unexpected typerquired: variablefound: value 
required: variable

Comment: Вот здесь ты пытаешься присвоить значение `COLUMN_1= " А"`. Нужно так `COLUMN_1 + "= А"`

Comment: Боже, такая простая ошибка. даже не подумал. Спасибо большое. А как вместо этого A подставить нажатый элемент?

Comment: Но в любом случае, ошибки нет, но и результатов нет , хотя тот же запрос в дб браузер выдает результаты

Comment: В приведенном выше коде есть похожий пример. Смотри метод getColumn1()

Comment: Значит не правильно подключаешь базу данных.

Comment: Если я просто вывожу столбцы. то оно работает, не получается именно вывести с этим условием

Comment: Попробуй добавить апострофы "= 'А'"

Comment: Как я понял  - сам запрос Select Colunm1 уже не выдает результатов